# Multiple gps tracking in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, gps, tracking

I was wondering if someone could point me in the direction of display the output of multiple gps devices at the same time in QGIS.

I have two GPS devices that are both outputting NMEA sentences through either a com port or over a TCP connection.

I can get either one to plot easily but not both together.